# Delete old files after X days by default with exception on certain dirs [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to fix the following scenario:

I have directory which has multiple subdirectories and files where I need to set something like retention policy, by default I would set to have files no older than 365 days where there are some special directories where I would like to keep for a different period of time other than my default value. These directories are specified in a txt file with the following syntax

Content of Drive:\Path\to\special_dirs.txt

```
D:\Path\to\vendor1 -396
D:\Path\to\vendor2 -45
```

This is what I have come up so far (It is working on the special directories only, the next part where I want to proceed with the rest does not work):

```
# Script to remove old files from Archive: D:\Path\to
# Declaring variables to be used
$controlfile = "Drive:\Path\to\list\special_dirs.txt"
$dir = "D:\Path\to"
$default_days = "-365"
$excluded_dirs = Get-Content $controlfile | Foreach-Object {$_.Split()[0]}

foreach ($line in Get-Content $controlfile) {
    $split = $line.split(" ")
    $file_path = $split[0]
    $max_days = $split[1]

    Get-ChildItem $file_path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($max_days))} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose -WhatIf
}

# Removing everything else older than 365 days old
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Include *.* -File -Recurse -Directory -Exclude $excluded_dirs | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $curr_date.AddDays($default_days))} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose -WhatIf
```

I'm not looking to remove directories even if they are empty, I just want to remove files, the last part of the script just deletes everything older than 365 day where there is a directory that I would like to keep 30 days more than the default period of time, any ideas on how to get this done?
I used the file list so that I can keep adding directories to vendors where I can keep longer than or even less than the default days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue with the following:

```
# Script to remove old files from DFS Archive: D:\Path\to
# Declaring variables to be used
$controlfile = "Drive:\Path\to\list\special_dirs.txt"
$dir = "D:\Path\to"
$default_days = "-365"
$excluded_dirs = Get-Content $controlfile | Foreach-Object {$_.Split()[0]}

# Removing old files from special directories first
cd $dir
foreach ($line in Get-Content $controlfile) {
    $split = $line.split(" ")
    $file_path = $split[0]
    $max_days = $split[1]

    Get-ChildItem $file_path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($max_days))} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose
}

# Removing everything else older than 365 days old
Get-ChildItem $dir -Directory -Exclude $excluded_dirs | Get-ChildItem -Include *.* -File -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($default_days))} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose
```

And I have modified my special_dirs.txt file to:

```
vendor1 -396
vendor2 -45
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?..

```
$30DayDirs = @('C:\Temp\Test1\','C:\Temp\Test2\')
$60DayDirs = @('C:\Temp\Test3\')
$365DayDirs = @('C:\Temp\Test4\')

foreach($file in $30DayDirs){
    $file = Get-ChildItem $30DayDirs -Recurse |where LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force -Recurse
}

foreach($file in $60DayDirs){
    $file = Get-ChildItem $60DayDirs -Recurse |where LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force -Recurse
}

foreach($file in $365DayDirs){
    $file = Get-ChildItem $365DayDirs -Recurse |where LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force -Recurse
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just  tried to implement it in my case, however the problem is as follow:
There are a bunch of other directories below C:\Temp\ in which case only two of them require a different time before they get removed, the rest and new folders should be kept for 1 year. I would like to keep a list file so that I can easily add new directories which need a different retention period